# Git: how to list all files under version control along with their author date?

Tags: git

Given a git repo, I need to generate a dictionary of each version controlled file's last modified date as a unix timestamp mapped to its file path. I need the last modified date as far as git is concerned - not the file system.

In order to do this, I'd like to get git to output a list of all files under version control along with each file's author date. The output from `git ls-files` or `git ls-tree -r master` would be perfect if their output had timestamps included on each line.

Is there a way to get this output from git?

**Update for more context:** I have a current implementation that consists of a python script that iterates through every file under source control and does a `git log` on each one, but I'm finding that that doesn't scale well. The more files in the repo, the more `git log` calls I have to make. So that has led me to look for a way to gather this info from git with fewer calls (ideally just 1).

Comment: @derekvanvivliet What do you mean by file author? There can be multiple people who have made commits to a file.

Comment: Unfortunately git lacks "tree blame" i.e. "`git blame <directory>`" to get output like in e.g. GitHub tree view.  You can get data for each individual file with `git log -1 --tformat=... --follow=<filename>` with custom format, iterating over `git ls-tree --names-only -r HEAD`, but it won't be fast.

Comment: @ansh0l not file author, author date. I mean the date that the file was last modified in source control

Comment: @JakubNarębski I tried that method, but as you mentioned, it wasn't fast. I need something more performant than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a list of all files under version control along with each file's author date

Scaling isn't a problem with this one:

```
#!/bin/sh
temp="${TMPDIR:-/tmp}/@@@commit-at@@@$$"
trap "rm '$temp'" 0 1 2 3 15
git log --pretty=format:"%H%x09%at" --topo-order --reverse "$@" >"$temp"
cut -f1 "$temp" \
| git diff-tree -r --root --name-status --stdin \
| awk '
        BEGIN {FS="\t"; OFS="\t"}
        FNR==1{++f}
        f==1  {at[$1]=$2; next}
        NF==1 {commit=$1; next}
        $1=="D"{$1=""; delete last[$0]; next} # comment to also show deleted files
              {did=$1;$1=""; last[$0]=at[commit]"\t"did}
        END   {for (f in last) print last[f]f}
 ' "$temp" - \
| sort -t"`printf '\t'`" -k3
```

Comment: that works really well. Can you explain what you're doing with `git log` and `git diff-tree` there? I'd like to implement it in python if it would perform anywhere near as well.

Comment: Essentially all the efficiency here is the bulk diff-tree handling, if python maintains an object cache it could do as well. The log dumps SHA + unix-timestamp-format author date from the root forward, so the latest-actually-committed %at is the one registered, then the cut|diff-tree spits for each a SHA line then name-status pairs into the awk which loads up the sha/timestamp pairs first and then loads up the name->timestamp-via-commit-SHA lookup+given-status table and dumps that table at the end. Best way to see what's going on is to run the commands yourself on a toy repo.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote the following script to output for each file the path, short hashtag and date.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#
# Author: R.F. Smith <rsmith@xs4all.nl>
# $Date: 2013-03-23 01:09:59 +0100 $
#
# To the extent possible under law, Roland Smith has waived all
# copyright and related or neighboring rights to gitdates.py. This
# work is published from the Netherlands. See
# http://creativecommons.org/publicdomain/zero/1.0/

"""For each file in a directory managed by git, get the short hash and
data of the most recent commit of that file."""

import os
import sys
import subprocess
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool

# Suppres terminal windows on MS windows.
startupinfo = None
if os.name == 'nt':
    startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
    startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

def filecheck(fname):
    """Start a git process to get file info. Return a string
    containing the filename, the abbreviated commit hash and the
    author date in ISO 8601 format.

    Arguments:
    fname -- Name of the file to check.
    """
    args = ['git', '--no-pager', 'log', '-1', '--format=%h|%at', fname]
    try:
        b = subprocess.check_output(args, startupinfo=startupinfo)
        data = b.decode()[:-1]
        h, t = data.split('|')
        out = (fname[2:], h, time.gmtime(float(t)))
    except (subprocess.CalledProcessError, ValueError):
        return (fname[2:], '', time.gmtime(0.0))
    return out

def main():
    """Main program."""
    # Get a list of all files
    allfiles = []
    # Get a list of excluded files.
    exargs = ['git', 'ls-files', '-i', '-o', '--exclude-standard']
    exc = subprocess.check_output(exargs).split()
    if not '.git' in os.listdir('.'):
        print('This directory is not managed by git.')
        sys.exit(0)
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
        if '.git' in dirs:
            dirs.remove('.git')
        tmp = [os.path.join(root, f) for f in files if f not in exc]
        allfiles += tmp
    # Gather the files' data using a Pool.
    p = Pool()
    filedata = []
    for res in p.imap_unordered(filecheck, allfiles):
        filedata.append(res)
    p.close()
    # Sort the data (latest modified first) and print it
    filedata.sort(key=lambda a: a[2], reverse=True)
    dfmt = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %Z'
    for name, tag, date in filedata:
        print('{}|{}|{}'.format(name, tag, time.strftime(dfmt, date)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks @RolandSmith. In truth, I'm currently using a script that is similar to this one. I was hoping there was a way to get that information (file names associated with their last modified date) out of git with fewer calls to `git log` or ideally one call.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is run `git ls-files` and add all of them into an array, then run `git log $date_args --name-only`, and then parse that output and remove those files from the array while adding the date information to a dictionary, and stop the processing once the array is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
git ls-files -z | xargs -0 -n1 -I{} -- git log -1 --format='%at {}' {}
```

This works on `bash` and probably `sh`.