# How to get a list of filenames and last modified dates from Git

Tags: git, git-diff

So I am fairly new to Git. Primarily I have been using Sourcetree as a visual aid. Across a range of projects I wanted to get a list of files and their most recent modified date, since a given date.

I see that I can use "git diff --name-only " from the commandline but presumably I can get something other than (-only) and this appears to be against a single project.

So what I am looking for is not related to single projects as per the question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166483/git-how-to-list-all-files-under-version-control-along-with-their-author-date) But rather I am trying to get a review across active projects such that I can see where the focus was for energy spent on multiple incomplete ad-hoc projects. I know Ad-Hoc is a dirty scenario for some but this situation is not likely to change any time soon and is not a development choice I have made but the reality of an ongoing buisness situation.

So as per response to @torek below, I have multiple, simple, largely unforked clones, using shared source libraries. I want to merge, manually if need be, advantagous changes in those back into a MasterLibraryRepo (which is a collection of individual source-code libraries), and need a quick way to review where to focus my effort.

- ProjectA.LibA LastCommitDate    (might modify File LibA MasterLibRepo etc)
- ProjectA.LibB LastCommitDate
- ProjectB.LibF LastCommitDate
- ProjectZ.LibQ LastChnageDate

etc

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git: how to list all files under version control along with their author date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19166483/git-how-to-list-all-files-under-version-control-along-with-their-author-date)

Answer (score 0):

Edit regarding question-edit: Git has no built in facility for dealing with multiple projects.  You could make a repository of your own with multiple remotes, and maintain (in that repository) *N* separate commit graph subsets and hence run *N* separate `git diff`s on a single repo instead of one `git diff` on *N* separate repos, but it's not clear you would gain much if anything from this.

---

**TL;DR answer:** try `git log -1 --pretty=format:%cd $sha..HEAD -- <filename>`, once for each interesting `<filename>` and using your starting hash `$sha`.  But see below for numerous caveats.

You may need to define the problem more precisely first; here is an example of why.  Note that I assume that the "modified date" of a file is really "the date attached to a commit, where that commit modifies the file with respect to the start-point commit you have identified."

Suppose we have the following commit graph:

```
                C--D--G--H     <-- xyz-branch
               /    \
...--o--S--A--B--E---F--I--J   <-- etc-branch
```

Here commit `S` is our chosen starting point commit (the one you picked for looking for "modified since" cases).  Let's say there are 30 files in that commit, and commit `A` is the same as `S` except that file `a.a` was modified (so commit `A` has the 29 identical files and one different, namely `a.a`).

Now, if `a.a` is entirely unchanged in every subsequent commit, obviously the date we want for `a.a` is the author or committer date attached to commit `A`.  But if that file is also modified in commit `J`, you probably want the one of the dates attached to `J` instead.

But what if file `a.a` is modified in commit `H` as well?  Both `H` and `J` are descendants of `A`: which one should we pick as "last modified"?  If you have a specific target branch such as `xyz-branch`, then the most recent would be `H`, not `J`, even if the date(s) on `J` are newer, since commit `J` is only on `etc-branch`.  If the specific branch is `etc-branch` then we'd care about `J` and not `H`.

Even with this (`etc-branch`) constraint, though, if `a.a` is modified in both `C` and `E`, you may need a strategy to pick one of these *unless* you want to assign these changes to commit `F`.  `F` is a merge commit and hence picks up changes from both sides of the branch—but some git commands, notably including `git log` and `git rev-list`, will tend to skip `F` in various cases, which may hide it from your scan.  Then again, this may be what you want: you might want to ignore merge commits and concentrate only on the non-merges that are, in normal cases,<sup>1</sup> the source of all changes brought into the merge.

You must also decide what it means if some commit deletes `a.a` entirely.  Is that a change?  What happens if a subsequent commit restores `a.a`?  What if it's changed in one "side" of the internal branch (e.g., commit `C`) and then changed back (e.g., in `D` or `F`)?

(I cannot guess what you want; you will have to decide on these things yourself.)

In any case, it's worth pointing out that `git diff` simply compares two commits pair-wise.  For instance, if you run `git diff --name-status etc-branch~6 etc-branch`, Git will compare commit `S` against commit `J`.  (`S` comes from `etc-branch~6`: count back six first-parents.  I assume that the first parent of merge `F` is commit `E` here, though it's impossible to tell from this graph drawing.  If the first parent of `F` is actually `D` rather than `E`, this compares commit `A` against commit `F` instead.)  This tells you what is changed from `S` to `J`, but nothing about *how it got that way*: you may see `a.a` changed, but you do not know if it was changed in `B`, `E`, and/or `I`, or perhaps even deleted in `I` and resurrected in `J`, for instance.

Depending on what kinds of constraints you want, there is a relatively quick way to find commit(s) that touched any specific file.  The `git log` and `git rev-list` commands—these are almost the same command, really, and are implemented by a single top level file—can be told to "simplify" commit history, including filtering away all but some listed file(s).  For instance, if you want to know about `builtin/log.c` (which implements both `git log` and `git rev-list`), you can run:

```
git log -p -- builtin/log.c
```

which prints out commits that modify the file (including some merges) and then shows a patch to see what exactly changed in that file (often showing nothing for these same merges, because `git log -p` skips merges: this particular command is a bit schizoid, or at least confused, do we want to see merges or not?!):

```
$ git log --format=short -p -- builtin/log.c | sed 's/@pobox/ pobox/'
commit cafef3d7ad3ed58d9c976bdeb604cff6b4c1f82b
Merge: 7c137bb 915c96d
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>

    Merge branch 'lt/pretty-expand-tabs'

commit 0893eec85fca0f76039a96cbbcd3592ff8571c24
Author: Junio C Hamano <gitster pobox.com>

    pretty: enable --expand-tabs by default for selected pretty formats

diff --git a/builtin/log.c b/builtin/log.c
index e00cea7..e5775ae 100644
--- a/builtin/log.c
+++ b/builtin/log.c
@@ -1281,6 +1281,7 @@ int cmd_format_patch(int argc, const char **argv, const ch
        git_config(git_format_config, NULL);
        init_revisions(&rev, prefix);
        rev.commit_format = CMIT_FMT_EMAIL;
+       rev.expand_tabs_in_log_default = 0;
        rev.verbose_header = 1;
        rev.diff = 1;
        rev.max_parents = 1;
```

(There is much more; I just snipped it off at this point—but note that it logged the merge, then logged a non-merge commit before the merge, showing part of what ultimately went into the merge.)

Using `--pretty=format:...` or `--format=...` and skipping `-p`, you can get just the author or committer date from `git log`.  This will include merges; to skip them, add `--no-merges`.  To limit the range of commits examined, add your start and end point, which I am guessing are your chosen hash (`$sha` in the one line answer) and `HEAD`.  Add `-1` (that's a digit-one) to make Git stop after printing just one commit. The commit chosen and printed is the one with the newest committer-date: `git log` always sorts what it prints, using the committer date by default.  The format directive `%cd` prints the committer date.

If you want the author date, use `%ad` instead of `%cd`, but note that you probably then also want to use `--author-date-order` to get Git to sort by author date rather than committer date.  This sort obeys the graph topology, which means that even if commit `J` is older than commit `I`,<sup>2</sup> Git will sort `J` before `I`.  This is different from the default (committer date) sort, which ignores topology: it will show commit `I` because it is newer than `J` (well, it will show `I` as long as the file in question is modified from `F` to `I`: note that the *tree* comparison obeys the graph topology, it's the sorting by commit date comparison that ignores the topology).

(You can force commit date sorting to obey topology by adding `--topo-order`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>As this phrasing implies, a merge *can* contain changes that appear in none of its parents.  Such merges are sometimes called "evil merges" and it can be hard to find changes that were slipped in this way.

<sup>2</sup>That might seem impossible, but imagine we boot the computer up with the date set to next year, make a commit, reboot and set the date back to now, and make another commit.  (Rebooting is not actually required—it is only meant to make visualizing this easier.)  The commit we made first is newer than the commit we just made, and in fact, will stay newer than *every* new commit until another year passes.

Comment: thanks for providing such a lengthy answer, however to be honest my situation is way more simple than the kind of scenarios you have addressed. I am in a totaly ad-hoc sole developer basis. I simply have to deal with the shifting sands. So multiple projects, that are evolving JIT style. Projects almost entirely single clones without forks. So the situation is quite simple. The reason I want to be able to review the latest commits per file is so that, I can easily periodically review and merge advantagous source-code library method additions/changes back into shared library files.

Comment: In otherwords I just want to be able to quickly review: ProjectA.LibA - LastCommitDate, ProjectB.LibF LastCommitDate etc

Comment: It sounds like what you want is `git diff <somecommit> <lastcommit> -- <paths>`, where `<somecommit>` is the commit you last looked at.  If you use `git fetch` and then review, those would be `git diff master origin/master` (for whatever files you care about), then once you are done, `git merge --ff-only` to advance your local `master` to the tip-most of the commits you've now reviewed.

Comment: I am not sure I can use a formal merge process. As the shared files are copied into a particular project, and represent perhaps a single file from a MasterLIbrary, which is a collection of libs - but I need the comparison across projects, I have edited the question to try to make it clerer.